# Frame Layout not working in floating action in Android

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I  put floating action menu in my layout with frame layout.In frame Layout show map. Floating action Menu work fine But in map i can't perform any action like in map custom marker. Marker not perform click event also no any event perform in map.

This is my layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map_i"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
    android:id="@+id/fab_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    fab:menu_backgroundColor="#ccffffff"
    fab:menu_fab_label="Choose an action"
    fab:fab_colorNormal="#e0404b"
    fab:fab_colorPressed="#e0404b"
    fab:fab_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
    fab:fab_showShadow="true"
    fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333333"
    fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444444"
    fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66FFFFFF"
    fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
    fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
    fab:menu_labels_position="left"
    fab:menu_openDirection="up"
    fab:fab_shadowColor="#66000000"
    fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="end"
    fab:menu_labels_singleLine="true">
    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/fab_email"
        fab:fab_label="Edit an item" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_whatsapp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/fab_whatsapp"
        fab:fab_label="Edit an item"
        fab:fab_size="mini" />
   </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
 </RelativeLayout>
```